# Best practice for Archiving data from multiple entities in one table and form a report

Tags: sql, json, report, archive

I want to archive data from multiple entites(with different properties) in one table and form a report. Currently, I saved them as `json` format in `sql` table and based on the type of the `entities` I created  different reports. I wonder if there is a better solution for this problem?